# Uitable over whole window width

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I would like to programmatically (or in GUIDE) fix the [matlab-uitable](/questions/tagged/matlab-uitable) to be the whole width of the panel on initialisation. How can I do this?

All I've managed is to change the size in pixels of single columns. I would like the uitable to be 100% the width of the page at that time. When my window is in minimized form the GUI looks fine, but when I maximize it, the uitable is only about half the width of the page. (The uitable's height is not that of the whole panel though, around 1/2 of the whole page)

The GUI is written in [matlab-guide](/questions/tagged/matlab-guide).

This is the code that I am trying right now:

```
data = populateTable;
parentPosition = get(handles.uipanel4, 'position');
uitablePosition = [x y parentPosition(3)-2 parentPosition(4)-2]; 
set(handles.uitable, 'Position', uitablePosition);
set(handles.uitable, 'Visible', 'on'); 
set(handles.uitable, 'Data',data, 'ColumnFormat',{'numeric'});
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to set both the `position` of the `figure` and of the table to `normalized`, then to set the position of the table to `[0 0 1 1]`

```
f = figure
set(f,'unit','normalized')
set(f,'position',[0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5])
data = rand(13);
for i=1:length(data)
   col_names{i}=['Col. # ' int2str(i)];
end
for i=1:length(data)
   row_names{i}=['Row. # ' int2str(i)];
end
t = uitable(f, 'Data', data,'unit','normalized', ...
   'Position', [0 0 1 1],'columnname',col_names, ...
   'rowname',row_names);
```

Comment: You only need to set the `uitable` unit to `normalized` (and then the position to `[0 0 1 1]` indeed). No need to change the figure unit settings. Also note that setting the `unit` setting of any uicontrol to `normalized` is the (only) way to have them automatically resize with the figure, any other `unit` setting, and you have to handle the resize in the `ResizeFcn`.

Comment: guys thanks for your help. I have this in the initialisation function,

set(handles.uitable, 'Data',data, 'ColumnFormat',{'numeric'});

Im getting the data to populate the table and storing it into 'data'. How do I have to change it? I tried to do it but the width stayed the same, the height just came almost the whole height of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the uitable's ***position*** property when you initialize it.

First, get the position of the uitable's parent object. That could be a uipanel or a figure. Assume hParent is a handle to the uitable's parent.

```
parentPosition = get(hParent, 'position');
```

Then, create your position vector for the new uitable, and use the parent's width and height. You might want to subtract a few pixels for padding. I'll subtract two pixels here.

```
uitablePosition = [x y parentPosition(3)-2 parentPosition (4)-2];
```

You can probably set x and y to 1 or 2 as well, depending on where the table is positioned.

```
uitable( ... 'units','pixels','position', uitablePosition )
```

You can implement the same idea in your figure's resize function.

Comment: I didn't understand how to actually set the uitablePosition. my uitable was done in Guide. right now Im doing something like this:

parentPosition = get(handles.uipanel4, 'position');
uitablePosition = [x y parentPosition(3)-2 parentPosition (4)-2];

set(handles.uitable, 'Visible', 'on');

set(handles.uitable, 'Data',data, 'ColumnFormat',{'numeric'});

In the last 2 lines I have to fit in the position created in the previous 2 lines (suggested by you).

any idea?

Comment: set(handles.uitable, 'position', uitablePosition);

Comment: On the new suggested line I am getting this error: Error using set
Value must be a 4 element vector

Comment: There's an extra space in one of the above lines.  parentPosition(4)-2 rather than parentPosition (4)-2

Comment: the parentposition(3) and (4) are 1 and 1.000 respectively. therefore parentposition(3)-2 and parentposition(4)-2 are both giving a value of -1, and they must be > 0. when i remove the - the uitable doesn't even show. what could I possible be doing wrong? - see edit in original post to see my code right now

Comment: The units of the uipanel may not be 'pixels', so you are subtracting numbers with different units. What units is the uipanel in?

Comment: it was normalized and I fixed it to pixels. in pixels I think I cannot even maximize..

Now it ran but this is what I got..

this when minimized: http://imgur.com/wODx9Xv (which is practically the whole window, when I want it to be half the height of the panel and the whole width of the panel) and 
this when maximized: http://imgur.com/P0qyGXX ... 
This is how it looks in minimized form without setting the position as you suggested: http://imgur.com/QvITIfV 

Reminder: I want the uitable to always be half the height of the panel, and the whole width & I want to be able to maximize if possible!