# Matlab non-resizable Window

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I created my GUI with matlab-guide (pity :/)

I have a problem when maximising the window, as the matlab-uitable was not resizing (even if its normalised) with the rest of the window. I tried to fix the problem by changing everything to normalized, changing positions and what not but the width seems to stay the same. I posted a question here: [Uitable over whole window width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980988/uitable-over-whole-window-width), unfortunately, to no avail. Some people tried to help but I got nowhere. Someone suggested me to do something like this, which didn't work. The uitable does not even appear in the window.

```
parentPosition = get(handles.uipanel4, 'position');
uitablePosition = [x y parentPosition(3)-2 parentPosition(4)-2]; 
set(handles.uitable, 'Position', uitablePosition);
```

So the only way to solve this problem is if I force the user to use the window in minimized form only :(

I tried to search for ways to do this but still, I got nowhere. For example:

```
set(gcf,'Resizefcn','')
```

How can I make the maximize option unselectable? Or perhaps if you have an effective solution for the initial problem?

Please note that I am a beginner with Matlab so I would really appreciate non-vague answers that leave me wondering.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's very hard to give anything but a vague answer without any code to work with.

Comment: what code can I give when I dont know what code to use? Besides, I am using Guide, which doesn't require code to build graphical user interfaces. Let me re-update the first part of the question with some code.

Comment: just double click on your main figure in GUIDE to open its inspector, then you can see the option `Resize` right above the `ResizeFcn`, just change `Resize` to `off`, what i think should be already there as default when you create GUI with GUIDE